# Using Python to deal with pop-up windows in Mozilla

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I'm creating a script for my brother that automates signing in to his university account, downloads his calendar file, and then uploads it to Google calendar since that's what he uses. I've gotten all the way up to clicking "Browse" when Google calendar prompts me choose a .ics file to import, but when the explorer window appears to choose a file(windows common dialog box I believe), the python code kind of 'pauses', in that it ceases to function until that window is closed. Here's what I mean:

```
browse = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gc-dialoginput') 
browse.click() #Using Selenium here, this is the click that opens up that pop-up 'File Upload' Window

"""The showing of notepad here is just to see when this code would run. 
I have it minimized to see if ShowWindow works, and it does after the pop-up is closed"""

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, 0, "Untitled - Notepad") 

win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)

print "test"
```

[image]

The ShowWindow function and the print "test" line all work right after I manually close the File Upload window. My goal is to use win32api.SendMessage to send the filename to the input in the window, but nothing works while it's open :( I only have a small portion of the code here, but the rest works fine except when it gets to this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more info/ full code is needed, please let me know!

Comment: This question might be better suited for Stack Overflow, as Code Review is for reviewing code that already works.

Comment: Webdriver cannot handdle the file upload window that opens, it is not part of the DOM. Instead, send the full filepath to the input element BEFORE you click the upload button.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Selenium instead of PyWin32:

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

You can install Selenium as a plugin for Firefox and then record whatever you want to do in Firefox with it. Then you can export the recording as Python and edit it as needed.